# Is it possible to copy shadow shader from one object to another?

Tags: shaders, vertices

I have such a problem that I added a part from myself to the model from the game, but there is a problem with the lower part on it. I do not know if it is a Shadow Shader or Vertex.

add project files (models and textures):
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o8g9ba3fatau8ad/AABN80QOewtWAQKX1dmkS59Ca?dl=0

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd]

[image: 3rd]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: I'd love to. I'm used to stackoverflow that with a reputation below 10, you can't attach pictures. @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Answer (score 0):

This could be a "Shade Smooth" problem

[image]

which is solved by turning on "Auto Smooth"

[image]

or by clicking on "Shade Flat"

[image]

But for an exact answer, please provide the blend file

Comment: These are not shadows, as I have already fixed this and the problem has not been solved. But since I'm new to this, maybe I don't understand it that way.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o8g9ba3fatau8ad/AABN80QOewtWAQKX1dmkS59Ca?dl=0

Comment: @Maxim_R https://imgur.com/a/J2DyGBy I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, but I found 4 different materials applied to 4 different sections of the wall.

Comment: Wow.. I do not know how it happened, because I applied only one material that was in the texture library. The model itself is a standard structure from GTA 5 that was cut out for editing.

up: I examined the picture. The fact is that I added my own piece to the standard model next to it, because of this they have 2 textures. In total, there are 2 of them on this wall in the project. tnt and no. 002 there was a postscript due to the transfer of the wall from another file.